# XCode: which constraints are needed to have an image with the same size as screen?

Tags: xcode, swift, size-classes

In my app there's a single `UIViewController` whose only job is to display an image downloaded from a server. I would like this image to have the same size of the screen as default; moreover, as this image is a sort of recipe I would like the user to be able to zoom the image in/out in order to read better and that's why I have embedded the `UIImageview` inside a `UIScrollView`.

The `UIScrollView` has 4 constraints: the 4 distances between the `UIScrollView` and the `UIViewController` are all set to 0.

The `UIImageView` has 4 constraints to: the 4 distances between the `UIImageView` and the `UIScrollView` which contains it are all set to 0.

Anyway, as you can see from the following screenshot
[image]

the result is not as expected: there's a bigger distance between the `UIScrollView` and the top of the `UIViewController` and the image is much bigger.

Do you know how to get the desired result?

```
<!--Recipe View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="y5Y-bz-arP">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="VnP-A1-Srr" customClass="RecipeViewController" customModule="Fishmeter" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="J4Y-SW-LaP"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="Yuj-fl-Q0L"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="1xx-WP-lNU">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" ambiguous="YES" misplaced="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5rg-8n-qc9">
                            <rect key="frame" x="27" y="94" width="558" height="486"/>
                            <subviews>
                                <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" ambiguous="YES" misplaced="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Y0D-XM-XJ8">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="159" y="158" width="240" height="128"/>
                                </imageView>
                            </subviews>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Y0D-XM-XJ8" secondAttribute="trailing" id="P5c-2q-jZO"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="Y0D-XM-XJ8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="5rg-8n-qc9" secondAttribute="leading" id="VkK-Pa-vmE"/>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Y0D-XM-XJ8" secondAttribute="bottom" id="mzG-vW-1fV"/>
                                <constraint firstItem="Y0D-XM-XJ8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="5rg-8n-qc9" secondAttribute="top" id="uoZ-V1-kxX"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </scrollView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="5rg-8n-qc9" secondAttribute="trailing" id="PbP-OD-eRM"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="Yuj-fl-Q0L" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="5rg-8n-qc9" secondAttribute="bottom" id="TQL-96-UgX"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="5rg-8n-qc9" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="1xx-WP-lNU" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="XEX-ck-lZi"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="5rg-8n-qc9" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="J4Y-SW-LaP" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="-10" id="lL6-Dk-MZe"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="recipeImage" destination="Y0D-XM-XJ8" id="5pc-vd-Ak8"/>
                    <outlet property="scrollView" destination="5rg-8n-qc9" id="Ieo-Uk-HIB"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="cUt-8l-j6r" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="3265" y="-311"/>
    </scene>
```

Comment: Would it not be better if you use UIWebView? And set constraints on it as you required. It will default the zoom functionality.

Comment: Thanks...I'll try it at once and let you know. I did not know there was a UIWebView...I've been programming with iOS and Swift for very little time

Comment: @msmq I am afraid I have got the same result... there's always some extra space at the top (which now is grey) and the image is always too big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a UIScrollView to work correctly with it's content, the constraints of the scroll view's contents cannot be defined by the size of the scroll view. The constraints must reference sizes defined outside the scroll view.

So, remove the constraints from the UIImageView and set the constraints to be 0 distance from the top, bottom, left and right of the **UIViewController's main view**.

--T

Comment: I have tried to remove all constraints from `UIImageView` but now the IB says that there as a "Scrollable Content size Ambiguity"...which other constraints shall I give to the `UIImageView?`

Comment: My bad - add constraints to match the width and height of the main view also. That should sort you out.

Comment: do you mean I should make the `UIImageView` have the same size of `UIViewController?`

Comment: Let's start again, as I think I'm confusing things. Remove all the constraints from your image view. Now, add the original constraints that you had (the 0 distance from top, bottom, leading, trailing on the scroll view). Now, also add Equal Width and Equal Height constraints between your image view and the uiviewcontroller main view. I've just done this myself to confirm that it's all good ... it is ;]